# Is 700,00 jpgs too many for a WordPress site.?

Tags: images, uploads

I am helping a customer with a website( uses WordPress )  that is  very slow to load and sometimes times out or does not respond.

I notice they have 692,264 jpgs in  /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/  .

Is this too many ?  Maybe that many jpgs is overloading WordPress.?

`[root@vps ~]# ls -lh   /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/ |grep jpg |wc`
289628 2696652 22644222

`[root@vps ~]# ls -lh   /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/ |grep jpg |wc`
289607 2696463 23109003

`[root@vps ~]# ls -lh   /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/ |grep jpg |wc`
113017 1017153 8535518

Total 289628 + 289617 +113019  =` **692,264**

---

Total disk space for website is 17 GB

`[root@vps ~]# du -d 1 -h /home/xxxx/public_html/ |grep G`

`17G     /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content`

Is the website just too big , with too many files ?

Comment: Is the timeout on the front-end or back-end - or both - and does the theme or admin do anything special with those jpegs, or are they just sitting in the media library?

Comment: Unless they’re displaying all of them on a single page it shouldn’t matter.

Comment: It's worth looking at your database load too, in case you're missing an index or something that means wp_posts or wp_postmeta queries are slow, since lots of images in the media library will mean lots of rows in those two tables. Look at anything MySQL reports as slow queries, or check the query execution plan for the most common queries.